# Order notification - GPRS/SMS etc

Tags: php, sms, gprs, zen-cart

I am trying to make a site for a pizza shop.I am using Zen Cart.

I wanted to know, what are my options in terms of notifying the shop in real time when there is a new order. I find an email notification inappropiate for a pizza shop.

I am thinking of some sort of device (printer).

I know a little about an GPRS/SMS printer.

Can someone shed some light on an appropiate(small, convenient) option.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

How about an email to a cellphone text message?

For example 000000000000@tmobile.net (0's being my phone number) sends my t-mobile phone a text  message.

If you do want to use SMS, I'd recommend using a service provider. Take a look at: zeepmobile.com, I've never tried them, but they seem interesting.

Comment: Agree with this answer. Other providers to look at as well: Twilio (where I work), Clickatell, MessageMedia.

Comment: Twilio looks great! I'm very much interested in adding API support for my product. It also helps that your company's office is a block away from my business.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive notifications about new orders through Kruzda (http://www.vova-beg.com/shop/programs/kruzda/)

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.